# List ElasticSearch Index names only

Tags: elasticsearch

GET `/_cat/indices/` returns a detailed list of ElasticSearch indices including their size etc.

Is it possible to just get their names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that by specifying which columns you want:

```
GET _cat/indices?h=idx
```

In order to find all the columns available for a given CAT endpoint, you can use the `help` parameter:

```
GET _cat/indices?help
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has many options.

If you are only looking for name then below would be helpful

```
GET /_cat/indices?pri&h=index
```

Please refer the below link for detailed descriptions.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html